# Different projects join the same queue in TFS Builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have just upgraded our TFS 2008 to TFS 2010. We have a few project areas in our source control and in 2008 they all seemed to have their own build queue, i.e. we could have 2 builds going on if there were in different projects.

However in 2010 there seems to be only one queue. If i queue a build in project A and there is already a build going on in Project B, the Project A build wont start until Project B's build completes.

Can anyone shed any light on this matter?
Is it a configuration/setup issue that can be altered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS2010, each Collection has a Build Controller associated to it. Each build controller can have 1 or multiple build agents running your builds. So you can build multiple solutions in parallel, just the setup of the build environment is more *advanced* and scalable than in previous releases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : [TFS Team Build 2010: What’s New?](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2009/05/23/tfs-team-build-2010-whatrsquos-new.aspx)